# Javascript accessing "document" objects in a different context (react)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, document, getelementsbyclassname

I'm writing an extension that runs a content script to update some elements on the DOM.
The page giving me an issue is this one: https://app.crackingthecryptic.com/webapp/4mbb4Hg948

My code starts after all the DOM is loaded and run:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('sudoku-cell');
```

I'm expecting it to return a list of elements. If you check the debugger "Elements" you can easily find these elements in the DOM.

I don't understand why but if you run the above search in the console (Chrome / Firefox) with the "Javascript context: top" context it returns an empty list.

If you switch to "Javascript context: 4mbb4Hg948" then it returns the list of elements.

I believe this issue is related to some react context wizardry and I can't find how I would be able to access the updated DOM.

Answer (score 1):

It has nothing to do with React.

The document in the `top` window contains an iframe.

The `4mbb4Hg948` context is that iframe.

The document with the `sudoku-cell` elements in it is the one loaded into the iframe.

Comment: How would I access the document:
```
x = document.getElementById('legacyapp')
x.contentWindow.document
```
returns a "Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "https://app.crackingthecryptic.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame."

EDIT: just read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098021/securityerror-blocked-a-frame-with-origin-from-accessing-a-cross-origin-frame -> not possible